# How to arrange time series of previous year and current year into one ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a time series starting from `2015-01-01` to `Sys.time()`

I would like to produce a plot where I compare the two among one another:

Reason for that is to produce a overall plot showing values averaged by hours and week day in order to compare previous year and current year:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
# Some data
start.date <- as.POSIXct('2015-01-01')
end.date <-  Sys.time()
tseq <- seq(start.date, end.date, by = "hours")
data <- sample(1:10,length(tseq),replace = T)
sales<- cumsum(rnorm(length(tseq), mean=data, sd=sqrt(data)))
df<- cbind.data.frame(tseq,sales)
head(df)
# spitting date to days in week
df$week_days<-as.numeric(format(df$tseq, "%w"))
# spitting date to days in hours
df$hours<-as.numeric(format(df$tseq, "%H"))



# subset from 2015-01-01 to Current timestamp - 365 days
my_interval<- Sys.time()-1 -dyears(1)

df_15 <- df %>% filter(tseq < my_interval)

my_plot15=aggregate(sales ~ + hours + week_days, data =df_15, FUN=mean)


ggplot(my_plot15, aes(hours, sales, group=week_days, col=week_days)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()+
  ylab("Avgvalue")+
  xlab("Hours")+
  ggtitle("Average sales by hour and month 2015") + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

```
# from 2016 to Current timestamp 

# subset from 2015-01-01 to Current timestamp - 365 days

df_16 <- df %>% filter(tseq >= '2016-01-01')

my_plot16=aggregate(sales ~ + hours + week_days, data =df_16, FUN=mean)


ggplot(my_plot16, aes(hours, sales, group=week_days, col=week_days)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()+
  ylab("Avgvalue")+
  xlab("Hours")+
  ggtitle("Average sales by hour and month 2016") + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

How can I arrange them into one plots?

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by "combine" the two plots ? If you only want to arrange them in one plot (2015 above 2016), look at `grid` package : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html

Comment: Combine can mean many things. Please elaborate.

Comment: Hi Axeman, sorry for that confusion. I'm just not able to arrange them into one plot, where `my_interval<- Sys.time()-1 -dyears(1)` is the condition for the previous year

Comment: What should it look like? You want 14 lines in one plot? The y-axes have quite different scales.

Comment: @Axeman, the y scale in the upper example is confusing.Sorry, I could not otherwise introduce trend. But the original data  ranges between 0-200 where sales is just a count of how much item have been sold on one day in a particular hour. So I just want to visualize that in comparison to previous year among one another.

Comment: Ok, but I still have no clue what you want the plot to look like. Or do you want suggestions on how we would plot the comparison?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you combine the data into one dataframe you could use faceting via `facet_wrap()`:

```
my_plot15$year <- 2015
my_plot16$year <- 2016

my_plot <- rbind(my_plot15, my_plot16)

ggplot(my_plot, aes(hours, sales, group=week_days, col=week_days)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~year, ncol=1, scales = "free_y") +
  ylab("Avgvalue")+
  xlab("Hours")+
  ggtitle("Average sales by hour and month 2016") + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Giving the hourly nature of the data, I'd suggest a radar plot. Note that this should look a lot better with actual continious time data, since going from hour 23 to 0 would look a lot better.

Borrowing heavily from [here](http://www.cmap.polytechnique.fr/~lepennec/R/Radar/RadarAndParallelPlots.html).

```
coord_radar <- function (theta = "x", start = 0, direction = 1) 
{
    theta <- match.arg(theta, c("x", "y"))
    r <- if (theta == "x") 
        "y"
    else "x"
    ggproto("CordRadar", CoordPolar, theta = theta, r = r, start = start, 
        direction = sign(direction),
        is_linear = function(coord) TRUE)
}
```

Do some data prep:

```
# Get 2016 at the mean of 2015
my_plot16$sales <- my_plot16$sales - mean(my_plot16$sales) + mean(my_plot15$sales)

complete <- bind_rows('2015' = my_plot15, '2016' = my_plot16, .id = 'year')
complete$week_days <- factor(complete$week_days, 
                             labels = c('M', 'Tu', 'W', 'Th', 'F', 'Sa', 'Su'))
```

Plot:

```
ggplot(complete, aes(x = hours, y = sales, group = year, color = year)) +
  geom_polygon(fill = NA, size = 2, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_line(size = 2) +
  facet_wrap(~week_days) +
  coord_radar() +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]